# Load external translation files (jquery.i18n)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to put a translation script on some of my pages.
It's not very big, so I want to use the scripts from the CDN.

It works fine if I put the translation directly on the page with the script.
For example:

```
...
<body>
  <span data-i18n="foo"></span><br />
  <span data-i18n="bar"></span>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/8.1.0/i18next.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/1.2.0/jquery-i18next.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    i18next.init(
      {
        debug: true,
        // url.com?lang=en | url.com?lang=ru
        lng: new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('lang'),
          resources: {
            en: {
              translation: {
                foo: 'Home',
                bar: 'School',
              },
            },
            ru: {
              translation: {
                foo: 'Дом',
                bar: 'Школа',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        function (err, t) {
          jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
          $('[data-i18n]').localize();
        },
    );
  </script>
</body>
...
```

[works fine (en)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBRZS.png) | [works fine (ru)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jyR8.png)

BUT I want to use third-party files for translation instead of  "resources" object.
SO I also connected the i18nextLocizeBackend library.

```
<body>
  <span data-i18n="foo"></span><br />
    <span data-i18n="bar"></span>

    <!-- same scripts as above and one new one -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next-locize-backend/3.1.3/i18nextLocizeBackend.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      i18next.init(
        {
          debug: true,
          // url.com?lang=en | url.com?lang=ru
          lng: new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('lang'),
          backend: {
            loadPath: './i18n/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
          },
        },
        function (err, t) {
          jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
          $('[data-i18n]').localize();
        },
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

How do I use it, because in the console I get an error

> i18next::backendConnector: No backend was added via i18next.use. Will not load resources.

([console.warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJxFY.png) screenshot)
In all the examples that I found - this library is **just imported** and **I don't need it**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure i18next with the [i18next-http-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend).
Like described here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3#separate

So basically, load it: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/i18next-http-backend@1.3.2/i18nextHttpBackend.min.js"></script>`

And pass it with the `.use(i18nextHttpBackend)` function:

```
$(function () {
  // use plugins and options as needed, for options, detail see
  // https://www.i18next.com
  i18next
    // i18next-http-backend
    // loads translations from your server
    // https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
    .use(i18nextHttpBackend)
    // detect user language
    // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
    .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
    // init i18next
    // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
    .init({
      debug: true,
      fallbackLng: 'en'
    }, (err, t) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);

      // ...
    });
});
```